# Crystal Reports: Cross Join of tables used in report header, in details section

Tags: crystal-reports

I am getting problems displaying my details section. I have multiple tables used in my report header. I added another table "**CategorySkills**" solely for details section, applied group by on a column of the same table, put my fields in detail section. Now when I see "Preview", I am getting a single row multiple times.

Is there any way I can stop this repetition? (Please avoid suggesting linking all tables because all tables are disjoint).

**EDIT**

I have one cross tab in my report header, which is getting filled by a query which is returning **115 rows**. Now I have another table, returning **6 rows**, supposed to populate **Details** section. Now, instead of getting only 6 rows, I am getting **115 x 6 rows**.

Comment: It is really deficult to give an answer with the detail you provided.

Comment: ok @huMptyduMpty, let me edit it for you.

Comment: Have you joined the two tables?

Comment: Have you try placing a `sub-report` instead using details section? Also in detail section, how many fields you displaying. if it is can you find the specefic field which causing to repeat the same data!!!

Comment: @huMptyduMpty, I don't get what you wanted to ask. If I have a subreport which uses a column of a table as input to its parameter, then I will end up using my `sub-report` inside details section. How can I use `sub-report` instead using details section?

Comment: I am grouping my details section by `Category` and we have multiple `Skills` (one-to-many). Now I need to link this SkillId with my `sub-report parameter` inside details section. `Category` and `Skill` belong to a table which is returning only 6 rows.